# LaTex, How to input a negative number in integral bracket

Tags: math-mode

When I try to do it, it only adds a minus to the integral bracket, otherwise, if I try with parenthesis, it inputs the first parenthesis. How do I do?

Comment: Just add brackets. I found the answer.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat never assume what I type is what I mean. I'll delete the comment (as it's wrong) and post a corrected version as an answer, thanks

Comment: Can you please show the code you're attempting to use, so we can better understand rather than guess?

Answer (score 3):

Subscripts and superscripts should always be in a brace group so

```
\int_{-1}^{10}
```

not

```
\int_-1^10
```

Comment: +1 for "never assume what I type is what I mean." :)